# What is the time complexity of searching in a binary search tree if the tree is balanced?

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, time-complexity

The given answer is O(nlog(n)) but I also look it up on Wikipedia and it says it is log(n).

Which one is correct?

Also what is the worst case complexity for search an unbalanced binary tree?

Answer (score 8):

The time complexity for a single search in a balanced binary search tree is `O(log(n))`. Maybe the question requires you to do `n` searches in the binary tree, hence the total complexity is `O(nlog(n))`.

The worst case complexity for a single search in an unbalanced binary search tree is `O(n)`. And similarly, if you are doing `n` searches in the unbalanced tree, the total complexity will turn out to be `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

The average time complexity of searching in balanced BST in O(log(n)).

The worst case complexity of searching in unbalanced binary tree is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

The Time complexity of a Balanced Binary Searched Tree is `logN`, as stated in Wikipedia, because as it traverses the tree, it either goes left or right eliminating half of the whole Tree. For an unbalanced Binary search tree, the time complexity is `O(n)`, it's basically similar to a linear search.

To make the tree balanced, you can use one `red-black` algorithm, `AVL` algorithm or several others.

Answer (score 1):

In any binary search tree the time complexity taken is O(h), where h is the height of the tree..
Since it is given that tree is balanced binary search tree so searching for an element in worst case is O(logn).